# Listening when state change via redux - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm new to reactjs framework and I have a bit of confusion if what is the right way in listening if state change after an API call.

use `then` and `catch` after calling an `action` via `componentDidUpdate`:

```
componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getHero(this.props.params.id).then((result) => {
            this.props.initialize({
                "name":result.name,
                "description": result.description
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {

        });
    }
```

or via `componentWillUpdate`

```
// Call the getHero action (API)
componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getHero(this.props.params.id);
}

// Then listen if the state change via `mapToStateProps`
componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getHero(this.props.params.id);
}
componentWillUpdate(){
        this.props.initialize({
            "name":this.props.heroes.name,
            "description": this.props.heroes.description
        });
    }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Redux?

Comment: @Pavlo on the second block with the componentWillUpdate, I dispatch a data from my action after I fetch the data via api so componentWillUpdate will trigger because the props change via mapStateToProps. That's why I'm asking if did it correctly? May I ask for your suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Listen for changes in [componentWillUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate)

> componentWillUpdate() is invoked immediately before rendering when new props or state are being received. **Use this as an opportunity to perform preparation before an update occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.**

Load data in [componentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. **If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request**. Setting state in this method will trigger a re-rendering.

Comment: You can have a look on this [example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/async/src/containers/App.js) of the creator of Redux